# Expanding user cards

Tags: discussion, support

Until yesterday I saw everywhere the normal "simple" user card under questions and answers. It has the small avatar, name, rep and badge count. But this changed now and I wanted to read again the page explaining the different appearances of user cards, but I can't find the page.

What I'm seeing now, is some users still having the small user card, which does not expand when I hover mouse pointer on them, while some users having the small user card but it does expand when mouse-over, and a third kind that only shows the small avatar/icon but no other information until a mouse-over brings up an expanded user card. Why did this happen? Where is the page that explains the different versions of user cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the page, at last.

"Established user" privileges info page gives examples and explanation on expanding user cards. It also shows how to trick the system not to show expanded user card, and more. Pretty much explains the system.

Link: 
https://photo.stackexchange.com/privileges/established-user

Then the last kind of user card in question was an avatar only version. That almost surely is a internet browser bug, nothing to do with Stackexchange.

Answer (score 3):

[How does the User Card popup work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/how-does-the-user-card-popup-work)

Basically there some minimum requirements - if the user doesn't have much in the way of profile information, there isn't any use in expanding it.

Comment: Thanks, good info there, though not the page I was looking for. Anyway, I think I can live with this. Maybe it is my IE-browser acting up, after all.